# Issue with parsing jQuery post response

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

This is using jQuery 1.9.1.

The returned XML is this (verified with wireshark):
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <boolean xmlns="http://ws.web.foo.com/">false</boolean>`

Here is the code:

```
    CheckForValidReservation()
    {
    var xmlDoc;
    var ResName = document.getElementById('Lab_Support_Reservation_Information.Reservation_Name').value;
       var data='hello';
       jQuery.post('http://foo.com/passthru.asmx/ValidateReservation',{ReservationName:ResName},
      function(response) 
      {     
        data = response;
        //alert(data);
        alert(data.find('boolean').text());
        //xmlDoc= jQuery.parseXML(data);
      }).error(function(){
      alert('Sorry could not validate Reservation Name');
    });
    }
```

When I do an `alert(data)` I get `object XMLDocument`. So I don't think I need to use the line `xmlDoc= jQuery.parseXML(data);` (hence why it is commented out). I've also just tried `alert(data.find('*').eq(0)[0].nodeName)`. None of these things work, they just error. If I do use jQuery.parseXML on data, it also errors out.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

I can change the web service to return different XML if needed.

thanks,

lee

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? If you're expecting that `.find()` to be the jQuery `.find()`, well, you haven't wrapped `data` up as a jQuery object ...

Comment: Your XML only has one node, there's nothing to find, try `$(data).get(0).nodeName` and see what you get

Comment: ^ or `$(data).filter('boolean').text()`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing this in a 3rd party application and it is not very user friendly for capturing error messages.

Comment: `$(data).get(0).nodeName` & `$(data).filter('boolean').text()' both throw the error " Cannot read property 'get' of null" or  Cannot read property 'filter' of null.

Even with an alert of data displays 'object XMLDocument'

Comment: If `$(data)` returns `null`, and not a jQuery object, you have a problem

Comment: Finally threw together a webpage using jQuery 1.9.1 using the same code and it works like a charm. There must be something in the 3rd party application that is interfering with the normal jQuery functionality.